# Meteor unable to run application after adding ui-accounts

Tags: meteor

I decided to try out Meteor and found myself a tutorial to follow. 
So as one does I googled "Meteor tutorials" and this one is at the top of the results list:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/13/build-app-45-minutes-meteor/
Hey all!

So - I start following the tutorial but as soon as I get to step 2 meteor isn't able to run my application anymore.

The log is as follows:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


W2047-00:56:09.699(0)? (STDERR) /home/vidirr/.meteor/packages/mongo-    livedata/45bb567dec/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:359
W2047-00:56:09.700(0)? (STDERR)           throw err
W2047-00:56:09.700(0)? (STDERR)                 ^
W2047-00:56:09.702(0)? (STDERR) Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3002]
W2047-00:56:09.704(0)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (/home/vidirr/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/45bb567dec/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
W2047-00:56:09.704(0)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
W2047-00:56:09.704(0)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (/home/vidirr/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/45bb567dec/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
W2047-00:56:09.705(0)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
W2047-00:56:09.705(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/vidirr/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/45bb567dec/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
W2047-00:56:09.705(0)? (STDERR)     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
W2047-00:56:09.705(0)? (STDERR)     at net.js:441:14
W2047-00:56:09.706(0)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I checked in the the IRC room but they hadn't heard of the problem before.

TL;DR:

- I create a new app:

  - meteor create newApp
- I change into the new directory and run the app:

  - cd newApp
  - meteor
- Everything works fine.
- I kill the app, and add two smart-packages to my app:

  - meteor add accounts-ui
  - meteor add accounts-twitter 
    -(also tried accounts-facebook, same results).
- I start the app - and it crashes.

Info:

- Running a 32-bit distribution of Arch.
- HDD space is fine.
- RAM usage is about 1GB of 3GB before starting app - don't see any spikes.
- Nothing seems to be bound to port 3002, checked using netstat.
- Tried manually running mongod before starting app - no change.
- Tried creating multiple projects - no change.
- Removed ~/.meteor, reinstalled meteor, started a new project - no change.

Basically - I'm stumped. Seeing that I haven't actually written any code at all, I'm kinda blaming this on something else.

And since the guys in the IRC channel didn't see anything wrong with those steps, I'm also blaming it on something else then the tutorial.

Any ideas?

Best regards,

Víðir

Comment: Try restarting the PC. There's something with `3002`. Otherwise, if that didn't work, I'd say it's really odd.

Comment: Of course. Brainfart on my end.
It did work - but I'm kind of curious about what it was since I couldn't find anything bound to the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formalities, I'll place it here then.

```
Try restarting the PC
```

There is something using port 3002 and is not releasing it or Meteor just can't use port 3002 for some reason. If you can't manage to get hold of what's holding port 3002, then restarting the PC should do.

Comment: Checked - thanks.
Funny how you sometimes try EVERYTHING else before restarting.

Comment: Just a side note, from Meteor v0.7.1 mongod now runs on port 3001 instead of 3002

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with the latest Meteor 1.0 installation on my OS X 10.9: any application crashed after adding ui-accounts. In my case some other libs were involved and simple restart had no effect. What I had to do is completely remove Meteor and then install it again.

```
rm -rf ~/.meteor
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```